# s:List , how to clear it's contents

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have  with children inside it and I wanted to know how do I clear it from contents, delete all children after they were added dynamically.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set an empty dataProvider - `list.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection();`

Another way is to empty the existing dataProvider: `list.dataProvider.removeAll();`

Comment: What do I do when I want to add new stuff into the list after I have set a dataprovider?

Comment: `list.dataProvider.removeAll();` So that you won't have to assign new dataProvider instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove all the children by using the  `Listid.removeAllChildren()` function of `List`.

Answer (score 0):

If You have arraycollection use:
myAC.removeAll; where myAC is id of Your arrayCollection.

But mayby You are using array?
Then use function:

```
public function removeArrayElementsWithPop(aArray:Array):void
{
   const sizeArray:int = aArray.length;
   for ( var index:int =0 ; index < sizeArray; index++ )
     {
        aArray.pop();
     }
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi, I'm using spark list container